# symfony2 unable to receive json response in controller

Tags: php, json, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am developing REST API with FOSRestBundle. I am unable to send JSON response from controller. I am forwarding a request from fooAction of FooControllerFoo to a certain of BarController, when I try to return JSON response from that action I am getting blank array.

here is scenario:

**FooController.php**

```
class FooController  extends FOSRestController {
...

public function fooAction() {

 ...

    $response = $this->forward('ApplicationPApiBundle:bar:getByZipCode', array(), array('zipcode' => $zipcode));

    print_r($response);  //getting blank array here

...

}

}
```

**BarController.php**

```
class BarController  extends FOSRestController {
    ...

    public function getByZipCodeAction() {

     ...

       $response = new Response((array("one"=>"1", "two"=> "2")));

       $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

       // print_r($response);  // after printing I can see data in json format

       return $response;

     }

    }
```

when I print response in FooController's fooAction I see it as an empty array however when I print it in Barcontroller's getByZipCodeAction before returning it I see proper response object with json content.

Can anybody help me to figure out what is happening here?

EDIT:
Response object printed in Barcontroller before returning it:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response Object
(
    [headers] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag Object
        (
            [computedCacheControl:protected] => Array
                (
                    [no-cache] => 1
                )

            [cookies:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [headerNames:protected] => Array
                (
                    [cache-control] => Cache-Control
                    [date] => Date
                    [content-type] => Content-Type
                )

            [headers:protected] => Array
                (
                    [cache-control] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => no-cache
                        )

                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Wed, 24 Sep 2014 13:48:49 GMT
                        )

                    [content-type] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => application/json
                        )

                )

            [cacheControl:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [content:protected] => {"one":"1","two":"2"}
    [version:protected] => 1.0
    [statusCode:protected] => 200
    [statusText:protected] => OK
    [charset:protected] => 
)
```

=================================================================

**Response object printed in Foocontroller after getting response from forwarded action:**

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response Object
(
    [headers] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag Object
        (
            [computedCacheControl:protected] => Array
                (
                    [no-cache] => 1
                )

            [cookies:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [headerNames:protected] => Array
                (
                    [cache-control] => Cache-Control
                    [date] => Date
                    [content-type] => Content-Type
                    [x-debug-token] => X-Debug-Token
                    [x-debug-token-link] => X-Debug-Token-Link
                )

            [headers:protected] => Array
                (
                    [cache-control] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => no-cache
                        )

                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Wed, 24 Sep 2014 13:48:49 GMT
                        )

                    [content-type] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => application/json
                        )

                    [x-debug-token] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 168be3
                        )

                    [x-debug-token-link] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /app_dev.php/_profiler/168be3
                        )

                )

            [cacheControl:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [content:protected] => []
    [version:protected] => 1.0
    [statusCode:protected] => 200
    [statusText:protected] => OK
    [charset:protected] => 
)
```

please notice contents are empty.

Comment: Did you try to use `JsonResponse` object instead of `Response` ?

Comment: @YannEugoné yes tried JsonResponse getting same blank response

Comment: Is it due to subrequest since I am using forward?

Comment: There is some discussion here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/310 . And yes, I do think the FOSRestBundle view listener is the culprit.

Comment: @Rahul `$this->forward()` should return a `Response`. Do you **know** that it's forwarding to the correct controller action?

Comment: yes I am sure its forwarding to correct controller action, I am able to print response object before returning it to calling controller

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert with FOSRestBundle, but I think you should be doing something like:

```
$view = $this->view(['one' => 1, 'two' => 2]);
$view->setFormat('json');
return $this->handleView($view);
```

I believe what's happening at the moment is that the view handler listener receives no data, so overrides the response's content with null.

Comment: I just edited question title since i am able to send json response however when i receive it content are blank, i will try to send json response with view obj, will share the outcome

Comment: No change same empty array as response

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out the exact reason which is causing the issue it could be related to FOSRestBundle view listener.
Following the link mentioned by @Cerad in his comment, I decided to create service of the action where I was forwarding the request. So in my case I scrapped the BarController and created a service out of it although I could have opted to use this controller as service however I thought using separate class as a service is more feasible in my case.